# Add custom click event in each option of mvc3 dropdown in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create custom dropdown in mvc3 c#, so there can be provision to add click event in each option of dropdown.But I don't want any alternative like jquery or create for loop to add attribute manually.Is there is any way to create custom dropdown using htmlhelper or base class.Please help me regarding this.

Comment: What you mean about custom dropdown? If you are using a jquery dropdown, then most of the jquery plugins provide you the functionality to add events.

Comment: Custom dropdown mean, I want to create dropdown using C# base class where dropdown inherit properties and I want to add attribute to add event on each option also.I don't want jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your dropdown then you use the following way to define events.

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("ddl", ViewData["MyList"] as SelectList, new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })%>
```

And in your jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ddl").change(function() {
    var strSelected = "";
    $("#ddl option:selected").each(function() {
        strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
    });
    var url = "/Home/MyAction/" + strSelected;

    $.post(url, function(data) {
        // do something if necessary
    });
});
});
```